# XML Mapping is not workiing - C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, mapping

I am working in project for fun where, I have to deserialize my XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Remote Created="2022-09-13T09:45:05" Version="1.0.20.2.6.5" SerialNumber="2081" Site="Site" InstallationDate="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
  <Setup File="Qwerty" Name="Ytrewq" Encoding="Win32" Decimals="2">
    <Transaction SequenceNumber="1000609" StartTime="2022-09-13T09:42:52" EndTime="2022-09-13T09:45:05" Total="3.85" ExpectedTotal="0.00">
      <Identities>
        <Ident Name="Box" Value="1" InHierarchy="yes" />
        <Ident Name="Area" Value="1" InHierarchy="yes" />
      </Identities>
      <Charges Reject="0" Total="3.85">
        <Charge Name="Reject" Label="R" Value="0" Count="0" Total="0.00" />
        <Charge Name="10 counts" Label="" Value="10" Count="1" Total="0.10" />
        <Charge Name="20 counts" Label="" Value="20" Count="1" Total="0.20" />
        <Charge Name="50 counts" Label="" Value="50" Count="1" Total="0.50" />
        <Charge Name="1 counts" Label="" Value="100" Count="1" Total="1.00" />
        <Charge Name="2 counts" Label="" Value="200" Count="1" Total="2.00" />
        <Charge Name="5 counts" Label="" Value="5" Count="1" Total="0.05" />
      </Charges >
    </Transaction>
  </Setup>
</Remote>
```

And this is my object:

```
[XmlRoot("Remote")]
    public class Remote
    {
        //Remote
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Created")]
        public string Created { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SerialNumber")]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Site")]
        public string Site { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "InstallationDate")]
        public DateTime InstallationDate { get; set; }

        //Setup
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "File")]
        public string File { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Encoding")]
        public string Encoding { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Decimals")]
        public int Decimals { get; set; }


        //Transaction
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SequenceNumber")]
        public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "StartTime")]
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "EndTime")]
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Total")]
        public double Total { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ExpectedTotal")]
        public double ExpectedTotal { get; set; }

        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Identities")]
        public List<Ident> Identities { get; set; } = new List<Ident> { };

        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Charges")]
        public List<Charges> Charges{ get; set; } = new List<Charges> { };

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Reject")]
        public string Reject { get; set; }


        [XmlType("Charge")]
        public class Charges
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Label")]
            public string Label { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
            public double Value { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Count")]
            public int Count { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Total")]
            public double Total { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlType("Ident")]
        public class Ident
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
            public int Value { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "InHierarchy")]
            public string InHierarchy { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

After that, I have to serialize to JSON, which is working partially, and I got this result:

```
{
  "Created": "2022-09-13T09:45:05",
  "Version": "1.17.1460",
  "SerialNumber": "2081",
  "Site": "Site",
  "InstallationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "File": null,
  "Name": null,
  "Encoding": null,
  "Decimals": 0,
  "SequenceNumber": 0,
  "StartTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "EndTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "Total": 0.0,
  "ExpectedTotal": 0.0,
  "Identities": [],
  "Charges": [],
  "Reject": null
}
```

I'm not sure what could be wrong on the way I map this, but some values just return as null, and the arrays returns with no data. Everything below the 'File' is not workin properly. Tried to another types of elements/attirbutes and they didn't work. I'm quite new with C#, so I'm not sure what to do.
Can someoone help me with that?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about your model hierarchy. If you don't design your model correctly, you will encounter problems during deserialization.

Please take a look at the revised model structure below.

```
[XmlRoot("Remote")]
public class Remote
{
    //Remote
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Created")]
    public string Created { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SerialNumber")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Site")]
    public string Site { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "InstallationDate")]
    public DateTime InstallationDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Setup")]
    public Setup Setup { get; set; }

}

//Setup
public class Setup
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "File")]
    public string File { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Encoding")]
    public string Encoding { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Decimals")]
    public int Decimals { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Transaction")]
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}


public class Transaction
{
    //Transaction
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SequenceNumber")]
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "StartTime")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "EndTime")]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Total")]
    public double Total { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ExpectedTotal")]
    public double ExpectedTotal { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Identities")]
    public List<Ident> Identities { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Charges")]
    public Charges Charges { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Charges")]
public class Charges
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Reject")]
    public string Reject { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Total")]
    public double Total { get; set; }
    public List<Charge> ChargeList { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Charge")]
public class Charge
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
    public double Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Total")]
    public double Total { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Ident")]
public class Ident
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "InHierarchy")]
    public string InHierarchy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for, could learn better now how to do properly the mapping for my next projects. Just had to do few adjustments because the class ```Charges``` wasn't deserialzing the ```Charge``` properly, but after that worked.

Comment: hi @Emre, have just one questions, how can I put everything on the same level? Need to be everything on the root level. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi @miguelito, if you put everything at the same level, you don't need parent-child relationship but then you will lose your object hierarchy. Of course you can add the reference as an attribute to the objects and handle the parent-child relationship during mapping to the models that have parent-child relationship. For example you can add Transaction Id to your Identity object and put it at the same level. Then you can deserialize your objects to POCO objects and then create relationships during mapping your POCO objects to your actual models.

Comment: hi there, its me again here! need some assistance, how can I access the information from my sub-classes? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by your sub-classes? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML as Classes in the edit menu if you are using VS. Assuming your XML structure is correct this will give you:

```
    // NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Remote
    {

    private RemoteSetup setupField;

    private System.DateTime createdField;

    private string versionField;

    private ushort serialNumberField;

    private string siteField;

    private System.DateTime installationDateField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public RemoteSetup Setup
    {
        get
        {
            return this.setupField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.setupField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime Created
    {
        get
        {
            return this.createdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.createdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public ushort SerialNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.serialNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.serialNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Site
    {
        get
        {
            return this.siteField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.siteField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime InstallationDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.installationDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.installationDateField = value;
        }
    }
}

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RemoteSetup
    {

    private RemoteSetupTransaction transactionField;

    private string fileField;

    private string nameField;

    private string encodingField;

    private byte decimalsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public RemoteSetupTransaction Transaction
    {
        get
        {
            return this.transactionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.transactionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string File
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fileField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fileField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Encoding
    {
        get
        {
            return this.encodingField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.encodingField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte Decimals
    {
        get
        {
            return this.decimalsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.decimalsField = value;
        }
    }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RemoteSetupTransaction
    {

    private RemoteSetupTransactionIdent[] identitiesField;

    private RemoteSetupTransactionCharges chargesField;

    private uint sequenceNumberField;

    private System.DateTime startTimeField;

    private System.DateTime endTimeField;

    private decimal totalField;

    private decimal expectedTotalField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Ident", IsNullable = false)]
    public RemoteSetupTransactionIdent[] Identities
    {
        get
        {
            return this.identitiesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.identitiesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public RemoteSetupTransactionCharges Charges
    {
        get
        {
            return this.chargesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.chargesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public uint SequenceNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sequenceNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sequenceNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime StartTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this.startTimeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.startTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime EndTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this.endTimeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.endTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            return this.totalField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.totalField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal ExpectedTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return this.expectedTotalField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.expectedTotalField = value;
        }
    }
}

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RemoteSetupTransactionIdent
    {

    private string nameField;

    private byte valueField;

    private string inHierarchyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string InHierarchy
    {
        get
        {
            return this.inHierarchyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.inHierarchyField = value;
        }
    }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RemoteSetupTransactionCharges
    {

    private RemoteSetupTransactionChargesCharge[] chargeField;

    private byte rejectField;

    private decimal totalField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Charge")]
    public RemoteSetupTransactionChargesCharge[] Charge
    {
        get
        {
            return this.chargeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.chargeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte Reject
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rejectField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.rejectField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            return this.totalField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.totalField = value;
        }
    }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RemoteSetupTransactionChargesCharge
    {

    private string nameField;

    private string labelField;

    private byte valueField;

    private byte countField;

    private decimal totalField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Label
    {
        get
        {
            return this.labelField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.labelField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.countField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            return this.totalField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.totalField = value;
        }
    }
    }
```

Of course, such a method requires some work on properties, at least you can see the nesting of classes here. Then your deserialization will look like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Remote));
Remote res = new Remote();
using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileLocation);
res = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Remote;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I don't like using the "Paste Special", it looks very messy, I should've mentioned that above. Sorry about that. But thanks anyway for you assistance.